# Detect Windows processes start and exit events with C# without WMI

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, process

Using WMI's ManagementEventWatcher/EventArrivedEventHandler will result in creating another thread which I'm trying to avoid. WMI also is knowing for its delay.
So my question is : how can I detect Windows process creation/termination with C# without WMI ? is there a way to do this from unmanaged code ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan here's my question.

Comment: You might want to re-evaluate you software design if unusual requirements like that arise.

Comment: Are you looking to do this for all processes starting/exiting on a machine, or for one process specifically?

Comment: All processes yes...precisely (futile) : all processes of one user (all processes in a Windows session except those running under "SYSTEM" account)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Event Tracing for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (ETW).  Specifically, you want to look at subclasses of the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the [kernel event tracer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I haven't ever used this from managed code, but [this blog post (web archive link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160123050602/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielvl/archive/2009/02/02/how-to-consume-etw-events-from-c.aspx) looks useful.

And I don't know if this creates extra threads in your process.

In summary, you don't need WMI to monitor process events.  You can use ETW instead but I don't know if it exactly meets your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't need extra configuration, I want to do this using code only. I know it's my fault that this isn't explicitly mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, the only supported way to subscribe to process create/destroy events is through WMI. I think you are rejecting the option of polling, in which case it is either WMI, or bust.

Comment: should I ask another question to solve my original problem : how to "create and communicate" with a thread responsible for calling SetWinEventHook, having a message pump/loop and receiving callbacks, in c# ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand that, and I can't see how it is related to this question. If you want to ask a different question, why did you ask this one? I don't really understand.

Comment: this was my [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081803/force-setwineventthread-to-be-called-from-main-thread?noredirect=1#comment33547420_22081803) remember, my problem is related to this "For out-of-context events, the event is delivered on **the same thread** that called SetWinEventHook."

Comment: maybe I can call [GetProcessTimes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) just after a process exits ([Process.WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) ?