# C# callback on new process created?

Tags: c#, wmi, createprocess, eventhandler, managementeventwatcher

I want for my `callbackMethod()` to run whenever a certain new external process is created.

I was looking at the WMI apis, I have read to some extent I can attach an event handler whenever a process is started.

I have looked at this answer: [Is there a System event when processes are created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972039/is-there-a-system-event-when-processes-are-created)
And Created this code:

```
public static void setupMonitor()
{
    ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(new 
          WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
    startWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(callBack);
    startWatch.Start();
}

public static void callBack(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessID"].Value);        
    Process started = Process.GetProcessById(id);
}
```

How can I get the new process and assign it to a c# `Process` object?

**What I want to know is does this method also send an event if a process created as 'suspended'?**

Or do i have to use a different query

Thanks everyone

Comment: `seen the windows API - Win32_ProcessStartTrace` - it is not WinAPI, it is a WMI class. `would importing Win32_ProcessStartTrace directly be more efficient` - you are already using it, what do you mean by `importing`? Also, have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131316/detect-windows-processes-start-and-exit-events-with-c-sharp-without-wmi

Comment: You can get processname from that event and start Process.Start

Comment: @Zeller33 Also you are asking too many questions in one. You should concentrate on one thing at a time, otherwise the question loses it focus and becomes too broad.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the first question, it may have been unclear. The last two are the important ones and @LolCoder, I don't want to start a new instance of the process

Comment: Sorry people, I've answered parts of my own question, but I have one crucial question

Comment: `What I want to know is does this method also send an event if a process created as 'suspended'?` - there seems to be no documentation on that account. You probably have to [create suspended process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570591/how-to-create-suspended-process-from-c-sharp-without-p-invoke) and check whether it is detected or not. Obviously there is a risk that even if it works on one OS version, it may not work on older or newer version, but assuming that it is not a system critical application and that very few processes are started suspended it may be not an issue.

Comment: @Eugene -> yes it does activate the callback on a 'suspended' process, but I have found that `Process.GetProcessById(id)` doesn't work when suspended??? Or am i doing something wrong

Comment: @Zeller33 How exactly it doesn't work?